# android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-launcher-icons

am using the package [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) to generate launcher icons for my flutter app ,

using the method mentioned a the documentation I have added the file and mentioned it on my `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter_icons:
  android: launcher_icon
  image_path: assets/images/launcher_icon.png
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
```

and then called it using

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons
```

all files are being generated without a problem but when I run

```
flutter build appbundle --release
```

am getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR:D:\Flutter\dawri_flutter\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

        ERROR:D:\Flutter\dawri_flutter\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR:D:\Flutter\dawri_flutter\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

        ERROR:D:\Flutter\dawri_flutter\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

Comment: And have you verified that `ic_launcher.png` is actually a PNG file and is not misnamed?

Comment: it is a png , but how to make sure it is not really corrupted . ?

Comment: The error message tells you that it is not a PNG file.  What is your evidence that it is?

Comment: here is my res folder that have all the image generated from using flutter_launcher_icons
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f2bfea3f739a05d2a0f0778bd6cc0bf020230515164115/9260b7

Comment: and here is the image mentioned in the pubspec.yaml as a source for flutter launcher icons :
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b28dbf4619374dccfac8b4e2ce9c789820230515164354/5189cc

Comment: Your original file is a PNG image, but what about `ic_launcher.png`?  Is that generated by `package:flutter_launch_icons`?  If so, does the problem persist if you remove that file and regenerate it?